# The smallest volume possible for a lattice with integer distances?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, lattices

Let $\Lambda \subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a lattice satisfying $\|x-y\|_2^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $x,y\in\Lambda$. How small can $\text{vol}(\Lambda)=\det(\Lambda)$ be?

For example, in dimension $2$, the hexagonal lattice has smallest volume of any integral lattice, equal to $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. In higher dimensions, rescaling an even unimodular lattice by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$ yields a lattice with integral distances with $\text{vol}(\Lambda) = 2^{-\frac{n}{2}}$.

What is the smallest volume possible as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: Both your examples satisfy only $\langle x,x \rangle \in \mathbb Z$, not $\langle x, y\rangle \in \mathbb Z$ - is that what you meant to ask?

Comment: @WillSawin: Thank you, yes I meant $\|x-y\|_2^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ rather than $\langle x,y\rangle\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $\Lambda$ is an even unimodular lattice, then $\|x-y\|_2^2 = \langle x,x\rangle+2\langle x,y\rangle+\langle y,y\rangle \in 2\cdot\mathbb{Z}$, and so the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ scaling has $\|x-y\|^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After scaling your lattice by $\sqrt{2}$, the Gram matrix has integral entries, so the absolute value of its determinant, being a nonzero integer, is at least $1$. This gives a lower bound of $2^{-n/2}$.

Comment: And this bound is achieved whenever n is divisible by 8. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_lattice

Comment: What about an upper bound? If $n$ is not divisible by 8, then $D_n$ is above the lower bound by a factor of $2$. When $n$ is 1 mod 8, then $kE_8\oplus A_2$ is above by a factor of $\sqrt{3}$. Can this be improved?

Comment: @BenMares The way I understood the question, the OP wanted an order of magnitude. But I agree that the question of the exact bound is not solved for all $n$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $\sqrt2\Lambda$ is even, and $\mathrm{vol}(\sqrt2\Lambda)^2=\det(A)$, where $A$ is the Gram matrix of $\sqrt2\Lambda$. Thus $\mathrm{vol}(\Lambda)=2^{-n/2}\sqrt{\det(A)}$, so the smallest possible volume in dimension $n$ is determined by the smallest determinant of an even $n$-dimensional lattice.

The smallest determinant question is answered in the lemma of section 5 in Conway & Sloane's [Lattices with Few Distances](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.391.9846&rep=rep1&type=pdf). The answer is $8$-periodic in $n$, given by

| $n\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 8)$ | $0$ | $1$ | $2$ | $3$ | $4$ | $5$ | $6$ | $7$ | $8$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $\Lambda_0$ | $\{0\}$ | $A_1$ | $A_2$ | $D_3$ | $D_4$ | $D_5$ | $E_6$ | $E_7$ | $E_8$ |
| $\det A$ | $1$ | $2$ | $3$ | $4$ | $4$ | $4$ | $3$ | $2$ | $1$ |

where the minimum for a particular $n$ is achieved (usually not uniquely!) by the orthogonal sum of $\Lambda_0$ with some number of copies of $E_8$.

That one cannot do better follows from the classification of even forms of small determinant, [SPLAG](http://neilsloane.com/doc/splag.html) 15.8, table 15.4: if $\det A<4$ then the mod-8 signature is $\pm (\det A-1)$.

Returning to the original question, this shows
\begin{align}
\liminf_{n\to\infty}\ 2^{n/2}\mathrm{vol}(\Lambda)  =1,\\
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\ 2^{n/2}\mathrm{vol}(\Lambda)  =2.
\end{align}